# Why isn't jQuery 'closest' working when clicking on class element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some JavaScript generated HTML code on my page. Multiple sections/instances of the same HTML code is being generated and populated to the page. One of the DIVs in each HTML section is hidden using a CSS Class named `openrole`. I need to remove the hidden attribute from the next `openrole` DIV and do a `slideToggle()` on the DIV. When clicking on one Class element I am trying to find the next element of the `openrole` class, but no luck so fare.

I have looked through and tested tons of alternatives, but still no luck. I am hoping someone can point me in the right directin here.

```js
$('#role_info').append(
  '<li>' +
  '<a href="javascript:void(0)">' +
  '<i class="menu-icon fa fa-file-text-o bg-yellow"></i>' +
  '<div class="menu-info">' +
  '<h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading applicantinfo">' + papplicant + plusicon + '</h4>' +
  '<p >' + prole + '</p>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</a>' +
  '<div class="col-md-12 openrole">' +
  '<div class="col-md-6">' +
  '<p class="text-left standard-text">Selskapsinformasjon</p>' +
  '<p id="company_address" class="text-left standard-text"><i class=" icon-padding fa fa-home"></i></p>' +
  '<p id="company_phone" class="text-left standard-text"><i class=" icon-padding fa fa-phone"></i></p>' +
  '<p id="company_email" class="text-left standard-text"><i class=" icon-padding fa fa-envelope"></i></p>' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div class="col-md-6">' +
  '<p class="text-left standard-text">Kontaktperson</p>' +
  '<p id="contact_name" class="text-left standard-text"><i class=" icon-padding fa fa-user"></i></p>' +
  '<p id="contact_phone" class="text-left standard-text"><i class=" icon-padding fa fa-phone"></i></p>' +
  '<p id="contact_email" class="text-left standard-text"><i class=" icon-padding fa fa-envelope"></i></p>' +
  '<div>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</li>'
)
$(document).on('click', '.applicantinfo', function() {

  $(this).closest('.openrole').slideToggle();

});
```

```css
.openrole {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="role_info" class="control-sidebar-menu">
</ul>
```

No error messages are generated in the console. I guess I'm just not able to figure out how to write the correct JavaScript code based on the structure of my HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should be something like this

```
$(this).closest('li').find('.openrole').slideToggle();
```

[closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) check for the ancestor.

Answer (score 3):

`closest()` traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. Use `parent` to find element like below.

So In your case:

```
$(document).on('click', '.applicantinfo', function () {
   $(this).parent('li').find('.openrole').slideToggle();
});
```